# How can I store user preferences in a minko program?

Tags: minko

I would like to write a program with the [minko](https://minko.io/) Game engine.

Is it possible to write in the assets folder at runtime?
Is there some kind of key value store provided by the engine?

Comment: No, it is not possible to write to the `assets` folder at runtime. Store your data on the `sdcard` or have a look at [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Thanks. SharedPreferneces is no option to me since I'm searching for a cross platform solution provided by the above mentioned framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to write in the assets folder at runtime?

Yes, technically. You should be able to use classic C/C++ file system operations to write to the folder, just like we [read from it](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/framework/src/minko/file/FileLoaderWorker.cpp).

However, there is no guarantee that data will persist next time you run the application. In HTML5 for instance, it definitely [won't](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html#memfs). I'm not sure how it would behave on mobile, and I'm pretty sure that's forbidden on the App Store anyway.

> Is there some kind of key value store provided by the engine?

No, there is no persistent data storage in Minko. If persistence is not needed, you can use the [`AssetLibrary`](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/framework/include/minko/file/AssetLibrary.hpp) to store your assets, or a simple `std::map`. That would be pure C++, therefore cross-platform.

A key-value storage might be a great addition to the engine. There is already a JSON parser which might be enough for small data. You will need to implement the persistence layer on the platform you target (hard-drive on native desktop, vendor-specific directories on native mobile, Local Storage in HTML5...).